# Controlling pal files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

This is all the code, that I'm using to load a pallete file. But unfortunately, visual studio gives an error on `ASCIIEncoding.GetString(br.ReadBytes(length))` and says

> "reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference".

```
 'LOAD PALL
Public Shared Function LoadPal(filename As String) As List(Of Color)
    Dim colors As New List(Of Color)()
    Dim stream As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Using br As New BinaryReader(stream)
        ' RIFF header
        Dim riff As String = ReadByteString(br, 4)
        ' "RIFF"
        Dim dataSize As Integer = br.ReadInt32()
        Dim type As String = ReadByteString(br, 4)
        ' "PAL "
        ' Data chunk
        Dim chunkType As String = ReadByteString(br, 4)
        ' "data"
        Dim chunkSize As Integer = br.ReadInt32()
        Dim palVersion As Short = br.ReadInt16()
        ' always 0x0300
        Dim palEntries As Short = br.ReadInt16()

        ' Colors
        For i As Integer = 0 To palEntries - 1
            Dim red As Byte = br.ReadByte()
            Dim green As Byte = br.ReadByte()
            Dim blue As Byte = br.ReadByte()
            Dim flags As Byte = br.ReadByte()
            ' always 0x00
            colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue))
        Next
    End Using
    Return colors
End Function

Private Shared Function ReadByteString(br As BinaryReader, length As Integer) As String
    Return ASCIIEncoding.GetString(br.ReadBytes(length))
End Function
```

Comment: Sure, ASCIIEncoding is a class, not an object.  You can use Encoding.ASCII.GetString(...) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the answer.

> To Call load

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim colors1

    colerss = LoadPal(.FileName)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'LOAD PALL
    Public Shared Function LoadPal(filename As String) As List(Of Color)
        Dim colors As New List(Of Color)()
        Dim stream As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Using br As New BinaryReader(stream)
        ' RIFF header

        ' Colors
        For i As Integer = 0 To 7
            Try
                ''''''''''''First''''''''''''''''
                Dim red As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                Dim green As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                Dim blue As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                Dim flags As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                'MsgBox(blue & " " & green & " " & red)
                colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(blue, green, red))
                ''''''''''''''''''Second''''''''''''''''''''
                Dim red1 As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                Dim green1 As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                Dim blue1 As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                Dim flags1 As Byte = br.ReadByte()
                'MsgBox(blue1 & " " & green1 & " " & red1)
                colors.Add(Color.FromArgb(blue1, green1, red1))
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Catch
                MsgBox("Erro")
            Finally

            End Try
        Next
    End Using
    Return colors
End Function

Private Shared Function ReadByteString(br As BinaryReader, length As Integer) As String
        Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(br.ReadBytes(length))
    End Function
```

And why Load if u can Save?

> To Call Save

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

 SavePal(saveFileDialog1.FileName & "TheNameUWant.pal", colors1)


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

  'SAVE PAL
Public Shared Sub SavePal(filename As String, colors As List(Of Color))
    ' Calculate file length
    Dim stream As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    Using bw As New BinaryWriter(stream)
        ' Colors
        For i = 0 To 15
            'i dont know why but for insert the pallete i need change red whit blue and blue whit red
            bw.Write(CByte(colors(i).B))
            bw.Write(CByte(colors(i).G))
            bw.Write(CByte(colors(i).R))
            ' Flag in W:A always 0x00
            bw.Write(CByte(0))
        Next
        WriteStringBytes(bw, "PAL ")
    End Using
End Sub

 Private Shared Sub WriteStringBytes(bw As BinaryWriter, value As String)
        bw.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value))
    End Sub
```